# Adjust the zoom scale in Cytoscape.js trigered by the mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am using [Cytoscape.js](https://js.cytoscape.org/), to draw a Graph.
The problem is I want to adjust the zooming scale that the `zoom` event receives which the mouse wheel triggers.

Now when I scroll forward or backward the zoom increases or decreases more than expected... resulting in a bad user experience...

I couldn't find in the docs how to achieve or set this scale values...
I know that the wheel sensitivity is configurable but is not recommended to set.

Is there any way to establish how to scale in each wheel scroll?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property you're looking for is `wheelSensitivity`. Adjust his value to change the zooming scale. Be careful with it because it can sometimes affect the render.

I put it at 0.4 in the example below:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE>
    
    <html>
      <head>
    
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
    
        <style>
          body {
            font-family: helvetica;
            font-size: 14px;
          }
    
          #cy {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 999;
          }
    
          h1 {
            opacity: 0.5;
            font-size: 1em;
          }
        </style>
    
        <script>
          window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    
            var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
              container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    
              boxSelectionEnabled: false,
              autounselectify: true,
              wheelSensitivity: 0.4,
    
              style: [
                {
                  selector: 'node',
                  style: {
                    'background-color': '#11479e'
                  }
                },
    
              ],
    
              elements: {
                nodes: [
                  { data: { id: 'n0' } },
                  { data: { id: 'n1' } },
                  { data: { id: 'n2' } },
      
                ],
                edges: [
                  { data: { source: 'n0', target: 'n1' } },
                  { data: { source: 'n1', target: 'n2' } },
                  { data: { source: 'n0', target: 'n2' } }
    
                ]
              }
            });
    
          });
        </script>
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <div id="cy"></div>
      </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Thaks for your response... Nevertheless the warning annoys me, but I will test it in different devices.

Comment: The docs say this about warnings: Note that Cytoscape.js will print warning messages to the console to help programmers avoid mistakes. If you want to disable these messages, call ```cytoscape.warnings(false)``` to turn warnings off completely. You can turn them back on with ```cytoscape.warnings(true)```, and you can get the current state with ```cytoscape.warnings()```. It is recommended that you leave warnings enabled at least for development builds of your app.

Comment: @Corentin is there a way to arrange this with Javascript? For example, cy.style().width() is arrangable but I don't know how to do it with wheel sensitvity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cy.minZoom() and cy.maxZoom() to set the values. The zoom levels shall be maintained between this range on mouse and touch zoom. My example below is to set zoom on click event

```
cy.on("click","node",function(event) {
     
      cy.minZoom(0.5)
      cy.maxZoom(2.5)
```